# Bitmap with >= 100 bits in MySQL

Tags: mysql, bit-fields

I need a bitmap in MySQL with 100 bits resolution, but MySQLs biggest Integer type, BIGINT, has 64 bit. I want to perform bitwise and and or on it.

A Set is also not an option, since a maximum of 64 values is allowed (I guess it's implemented using BIGINT internally too).

The only option I see right now is splitting the BitField into 2 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with splitting my bitfield into multiple columns, works, although it's not a very nice solution - but since the length of the bitfields is hard coded it's no drama at all.

Answer (score 1):

What about using `BINARY` or `VARBINARY`?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-varbinary.html

This would allow for longer `BIT` lengths, but in turn you'd have fewer operations available without casting/converting first. Also, you could only have multiples of 8 bits...

Comment: can I perform XOR, AND, OR on it? I can't find anything about it.

Comment: As I said, you'd have to cast/convert them first. In the link I posted, you'll find an example of using `HEX` to get a hexadecimal string representation of your bits. I'm guessing that you could then convert that to decimal before using bitwise operations, as [documented here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex). That's obviously not very efficient or readable, so your original idea of splitting the bits in two columns might better suite your use cases...?